# Android Studio 1.5.1 can't open any projects or files

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the latest Android Studio version 1.5.1. 
I can't open any projects or files. 
It only shows the "No files are open" page. Most of the tool items are grayed out.

I tried to create a New project. The New project is created successfully, but this "No files are open" is displayed.

I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing Android Studio 1.5.1, but the issue continues to exist.

Also, there is no 'Fabric' or 'Crashlytics' plugins installed.

The issue is similar to the attached screenshot.
[image]
Please help me. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you add a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: wait for some time android studio takes some time to show files and indexing

Comment: I waited for more than 30mins, the files are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try and press

> CMD + 1

to see all the files of the project. If there is nothing try to start a new application and select an sample activity.

Comment: Its not working. Please find the screenshots attached.

Comment: Hmm I thought it might just not be showing you the project files even though it does load it in. Worth a shot though.